# How to convert a ISO8601 date time string to a simple date time format in XSL version 1.0?

Tags: date, xslt

I have a ISO8601 string (e.g. *date="2015-07-10T04:31:25"*) I need to convert this to the format: 
    *July 7, 2015, 4:31:25 PM (EDT)*

Even though I can write a template and use substring() to transform the string in the date time format. However I am not sure how to achieve the AM/PM and time zone information?

Working code templates would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "*Working code templates would be highly appreciated.*" Indeed they would.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? In 2.0, you use the format-dateTime() function.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how to achieve the AM/PM ...

It can be calculated from the hour component as:

```
substring('AMPM', 1 + 2*(number($hour) > 11), 2)
```

Of course, in the given input, where $hour would be `"04"`, the correct result is `"AM"`, not `"PM"`.

> ... and time zone information?

Your input does not contain any time zone information, so unless you want to hard-code `EDT` as a string, there is no way to get it.